# What is the RxSwift 3.0 equivalent to AnonymousDisposable from RxSwift 2.x?

Tags: swift, swift3, rx-swift

The [ReactiveX.io documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html) uses `AnonymousDisposable`, which was in RxSwift 2.x, but is an unresolved identifier in RxSwift 3.0.  What should I use instead?

```
let source = Observable.create { observer in
  for i in 1...5 {
    observer.on(.Next(i))
  }
  observer.on(.Completed)

  // Note that this is optional. If you require no cleanup you can return
  // NopDisposable.instance
  return AnonymousDisposable {
    print("Disposed")
  }
}

source.subscribe {
  print($0)
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To create `Observable`'s in Swift 3,4,5 you have to substitute the old `AnonymousDisposable` instance with `Disposables.create()`, like in this way:

```
let source = Observable.create { observer in
    observer.on(.next(1))
    observer.on(.completed)
    return Disposables.create()
}
```

If you wanna take some action when the Observable is disposed you can use the one you mention before instead:

```
return Disposables.create {
    print("Disposed")      
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this syntax from Swift 2:

```
NopDisposable.instance
```

has also been replaced with

```
Disposables.create()
```

Beyond that, it's interesting to note that, under the hood, `NopDisposable` still exists but is exposed via this `create` method. [Here's the source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Disposables/NopDisposable.swift).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
return Disposables.create {
    print("Disposed")      
}
```